# sudo mup deploy error

Tags: deployment, meteor

This was the last step to deploy my meteor app onto Digital Ocean using compose.io as a database, and I'm trying to figure out how to read this error. This happened after I installed an unofficial homebrew package on https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979 in order to run "sudo mup setup."

```
MacBook-Air:cb user$ sudo mup deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

Building Started: .

Started TaskList: Deploy app 'testSite' (linux)
[104.236.29.161] - Uploading bundle
[104.236.29.161] ✔ Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[104.236.29.161] - Setting up Environment Variables
[104.236.29.161] ✔ Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[104.236.29.161] - Invoking deployment process
[104.236.29.161] ✘ Invoking deployment process: FAILED


-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/root/.node-gyp/0.10.33/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/0.10.33',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/testSite/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/sacha:juice/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
gyp info ok 
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
/opt/testSite/config/env.sh: line 10: linda: No such file or directory
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
xtify/src/contextify.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/contextify.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/contextify.node: Finished
  COPY Release/contextify.node
make: Leaving directory `/opt/testSite/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/sacha:juice/node_modules/juice/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build'

> fibers@1.0.1 install /opt/testSite/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

`linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
└── type-of@2.0.1

semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.2
├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
├── supports-color@0.2.0
├── strip-ansi@0.3.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)
└── has-ansi@0.1.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)

fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers

source-map-support@0.2.8 node_modules/source-map-support
└── source-map@0.1.32 (amdefine@0.1.0)
Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Completed TaskList: Deploy app 'testSite' (linux)

Comment: There is often more error information in the logs. You can run 'mup logs' to see what is going on.

Comment: @JeremyS. This helped me to pin down my problem. Apparently I had an outdated version of Node installed.